# PHP curl ordering links in a table

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I have a table that I am scraping from my university website. The thing is the page only displays the top 20 elements in the table. The rest are hidden and can only be accessed via javascript.

I would only like the most recent elements in the table as the table has a created on column. The table has headers that are clickable which allows one to order the table by that particular header eg:

```
                     Name ---- type ---- created on
```

I would like to order it by created on. I use php and curl to fetch the url for created on: **https://vula.uct.ac.za/portal/tool/88e64ae9-c460-4acb-84b9-dac670a373b9?panel=Main&criterion=created on&sakai_action=doSort_sites**.

The result that I get though is the original unordered list that one would get if one was not ordering by a particular column. If I copy and paste that link into my browser however  it gives me the list ordered by **created on** in ascending and then descending order on subsequent pastes of the URL.

After I paste the URL and execute it in my browser, the url displayed to the user after the page has been rendered is the following: 
**https://vula.uct.ac.za/portal/tool/88e64ae9-c460-4acb-84b9-dac670a373b9?panel=Main**

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 88e64ae9-c460-4acb-84b9-dac670a373b9 could be a token of some sort.

Comment: Please, try to rephrase your question, make some paragraphs, shorten sentences and format Code

Comment: @WayneWhitty It is the hash code for the particular tool I am accessing on the site.